# Retrieve User data from user id

Tags: php, mysql

I have just started learning PHP, so please bear with me. I have two tables in my database, `users` and `appointments` tables. The `appointments` table has `idUsers`  as a foreign key for the `id` field in `users` table. I'm trying to display data from `appointments` table based on current user logged in. The problem is, it displays data from all users and not the one who logged in.

I'm using `fetch_assoc()` to get the data from the database.

```
<?php   
  while($row = $rows->fetch_assoc()): ?>
    <td><?php echo $row['idApp'] ?></td>
    <td class="col-md-10"><?php echo $row['fname'] ?> </td>
    <td class="col-md-10"><?php echo $row['lname'] ?> </td>
    <td class="col-md-10"><?php echo $row['email'] ?> </td>
    <td class="col-md-10"><?php echo $row['phone'] ?> </td>
    <td class="col-md-10"><?php echo $row['date'] ?> </td>
    <td class="col-md-10"><?php echo $row['time'] ?> </td>
    <td class="col-md-10"><?php echo $row['message'] ?> </td>
  </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

The expected results would be for the user to log into the system and only see the data , that they have stored against their id.

Comment: It's not your PHP that is an issue. It's your SQL. Please share that bit of code.

Comment: You're going to want to add a suitable WHERE clause to your SQL.

Answer (score -1):

you should to make "one to one relationship". for example you have two tables `users` and `posts`. the `posts` table must be some like:  id,user_id,title,...
so when you want to get posts articles by specific user run this query:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `user_id`= '.$_GET['id'].'';
```

however do not foget SQL injection!
learn PDO :)